# Angular function error under app.component.ts

Tags: javascript, angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

function log(target, name, descriptor) {
  console.log(target, name, descriptor)
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FreshShop';

  @log
  aSimpleMethod() {
    console.log("Hey There!")
  }

}
```

**error TS7006: Parameter 'descriptor' implicitly has an 'any'
type.**

Got this error while trying to create a function on app.component.ts

Would greatly appreciate your help, Im a rookie on angular.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
export function log(): MethodDecorator {
  return function (target, name, descriptor) {
    console.log(target, name, descriptor);
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FreshShop';

  @log()
  aSimpleMethod() {
    console.log("Hey There!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can simply

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

function log(target: any, name :String, descriptor : PropertyDescriptor) {
  console.log(target, name, descriptor)
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FreshShop';

  @log
  aSimpleMethod() {
    console.log("Hey There!")
  }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).